# Websocket closes immediately after opening

Tags: python, websocket

I am using the websocket-client library for python

This is the code I am using to open the websocket. I am sending the subprotocols and token in the header

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
        websocket.enableTrace(True)
        ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
            'wss://sample url',
            on_open=on_open,
            on_message=on_message,
            on_error=on_error,
            on_close=on_close,
            header=['1.0', ws_token]
            )
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
```

This is the request

```
--- request header ---
GET /api/action-ws/1.0/ HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Host: ec2-63-33-203-84.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8443
Origin: http://ec2-63-33-203-84.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8443
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 5btowNAZfan8qrT52bMqQw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Connection: upgrade
1.0
<token>
```

and the response i get is

```
--- response header ---
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 17 Sep 2020 17:34:45 GMT
Connection: upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: QNKV1fs8ddWGRM/lwkltrvBUMnU=
Upgrade: WebSocket
-----------------------
### open ###
send: b'\x88\x82\xc7P\x94\xe7\xc4\xb8'
### closed ###
```

So basically the connection opens and then closes after receiving a message.

I tried searching for an answer everywhere and could not find it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are your on_message, on_error, on_close? What do you see in the python console, do you get any errors?

Comment: `def on_message(ws, message):
    print ('message received ..')
    print (message)



def on_error(ws, error):
    print ('error happened .. ')
    print (error)


def on_close(ws):
    print ("### closed ###")


def on_open(ws):
    print ("### open ###")
    def run(*args):
        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(1)
            ws.send("Hello %d" % i)
        time.sleep(1)
        ws.close()
        print("thread terminating...")

    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())`

I don't get any errors.

Comment: So I get this error 

error happened .. 
can't concat str to bytes

Comment: Ok, that indicates that you do `"somestring" + bytes_from_socket` in some code that you did not share. "concat" is short for concatenation which is the adding that + does on strings. When asking for help, it is critical to post what error you get, and the code that gives the error.

Comment: So there are two servers I tested it on:

1. on my test instance I get the same response as pasted in my original post without any error
2. on my prod instance I get `### open ###
error happened .. can't concat str to bytes
### closed ###` in the response and not actually as an error

So I am guessing that error is from the server side in prod. But the same issue is happening in my test instance where I am not getting that error. I am not concatenating anything on my end.

Sorry to be bit of a noob but I am new to this